# Unable to adb pull in a batch file "for /f"

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I am trying to set a batch file to search for logfiles in multiple users profiles. it seems to find the files without issue however, adb pull fails with a error.

:Batch

```
@echo off

echo.
echo checking files
adb shell ls -d $PWD /data/user/*/com.myap/app_log/*.log
echo.

echo copying files
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('adb shell ls -d $PWD/data/user/*/com.myapp/app_log/*.log') do (
echo values are %%a 
adb pull %%a
)
```

Results:

```
checking files
//data/user/0/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log
//data/user/10/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log

copying files
 Values are //data/user/10/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log
' does not exist/data/user/10/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If i run the following without a variable, it works fine

```
adb pull //data/user/10/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log
1738 KB/s (81920 bytes in 0.046s)
```

This works but wont work when ls returns multiple files

```
echo copying files
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('adb shell ls -d $PWD /data/user/*/com.blackberry.enterprise.bscp/app_log/*.log') do set path=%%a
echo %path%
adb pull %path%
```

Comment: The Windows path separator is the backslash, so try to use them instead of the forward-slash...

Comment: I am using the forward-slash because the path is from android device connected over adb. unless i am not following your suggestion.

Comment: There are some situations where the slashes could confuse `cmd` though, but if the path is resolved by `adb`, it should be fine... Perhaps you could try to place double-quotes: `adb shell ls -d "$PWD/data/user/*/com.myapp/app_log/*.log"`...

Comment: tried that and it does not work. i dont think the issue is with the for /f loop, as in the do ( ) steps, the echo %%a provides the correct path. 

`//data/user/10/com.myapp/app_log/2016-08-09.log`

the issue is with the next command;

`adb pull %%a`

Comment: This works fine but only works when one file is returned

`echo copying files

for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('adb shell ls -d $PWD /data/user/*/com.blackberry.enterprise.bscp/app_log/*.log') do set path=%%a

echo %path%
C:\MDM_Device_Toolkit\Tools\adb.exe pull %path%`